# Distribution Significance

Tags: statistics

I am trying to determine if a distribution is significant given an overall population distribution.

The population as a hole has a 4% distribution for my question. If a sub-group of my population has 17 out of 202 or 8.4% distribution is this a significant difference? Is there a formula for calculating this significance?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Google "test for proportion". For example, here http://www.medcalc.org/calc/test_one_proportion.php